# Need to add certificate from txt file in runtime

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, pem, jks

Client has given 2 certificates in '.txt' format and I need to add these certificates during runtime while invoking the SOAP service. Unable to add '.txt' format files as i am getting like 'Invalid Format'. Certificates have "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" headers at the top and bottom of the txt file, so it's PEM type file (I assume). Any help/suggestion would be appreciable.

Getting below exception ::

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Using below code..

```
public KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    KeyStore ts = null;
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
    try {
        ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("publicCert.txt");
        ts.load(inputStream, null);
        keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(ts, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return keyManagerFactory;
}
```

After getting the answer, used below code and it's working

```
        rootInterIS = new FileInputStream("rootIntermediaryCertificate.txt");
        domainIS = new FileInputStream("domainCertificate.txt");

        keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(null);

        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate rootInterCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(rootInterIS);
        X509Certificate domainCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(domainIS);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("domainCertificate", domainCert);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("rootInterCe", rootInterrtificateCert);

        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEM format consists of a line `----BEGIN x-----` for one or more words `x`, one or more lines of base64 containing data with an internal structure matching `x`, and a matching `END` line. While someone *could* create a bogus file with correct BEGIN/END lines but wrong base64, unless they're actively trying to cause you trouble a file that looks like you describe most likely is a PEM certificate.

**A certificate (in PEM format) is not a keystore** and in particular not JKS. Java supports several different keystore formats, none of which is PEM and none of which is limited to certificates. Use `KeyStore.getInstance(type)` only to read a keystore, which you don't have; use [`CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)) to read a certificate file (actually in either PEM or binary aka DER, but at the moment you only care about the former).

In SSL/TLS the `KeyManager` is used only for a certificate(s) that authenticates (proves) your own identity *with a privatekey*, which you don't have. Putting a certificate without privatekey as you have in a `KeyManager` will be totally useless and ineffective. If someone has given you only a cert(s) not privatekey to connect to their system, that should be a cert(s) to authenticate *their* system, not yours; ask the supplier or look at the file(s) to confirm this. Given Java, you can use `keytool -printcert -file $file` to see the details of a cert.

You need to put that cert(s) in the `TrustManager` instead. Note both `KeyManager` and `TrustManager` use `KeyStore` objects, but in different ways for different purposes. So you create an in-memory empty `KeyStore` (do `.getInstance(type)` then `.load(null)`), *add* the cert from above to it *as a 'trusted' cert*, and pass that to the `TrustManagerFactory`, and then use the resulting `TrustManager` in your `SSLContext` etc.

Comment: Actually I got 2 files from client, 1 (domain) has single "BEGIN" and "END" tags and another one has 2 blocks of the same (root and intermediate cert, by name i can tell).. so do I have to load both these 2 files in TrustManagerFactory and load null in KeyManagerFactory...

Comment: @Balaji211: For a _properly configured_ server you only need the root cert in your TrustManager (standards require the server to send everything else) but I can't tell about a particular server you don't identify. You could experiment, or you could put all the certs in; worst case is if their server is compromised your code will still connect to and trust the attackers/criminals. If you don't have cert-and-key for client authentication, you don't need _any_ KeyManager just pass null for the first argument to `SSLContext.init`.

Comment: added both domain & (root + intermediary) certificates in trust manager factory